# Can not get range to produce a result in tapply function

Tags: r, range, tapply

just started to learn R but I can not get range to produce a result in this tapply function.I can get the ages and affill results but not the R as shown below.

```
ages <- c(25,26,37,56,42,25)

affill <- factor(c("U", "R", "R","D", "D", "U"))

tapply(ages, affill , range)

$D
[1] 42 56

$R
[1] 26 37

$U
[1] 25 25
```

Comment: What is your expected output.  Do you need `tapply(ages, affill , FUN = function(x) unique(range(x)))`

Comment: I m confused. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you look for something like this?

```
ages <- c(25,26,37,56,42,25)

affill <- factor(c("U", "R", "R","D", "D", "U"))

my_range <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  max(x, na.rm = na.rm) - min(x, na.rm = na.rm)
}

tapply(ages, affill , my_range)
# D  R  U 
# 14 11  0
```

You can construct your own custom function that computes the range of a numerical vector, instead of returning the default range in R.